# Subir archivos en app Android Studio con WerbViewer

Tags: android-studio, web, archivo

Estoy diseñando una app en Android Studio, es muy basica, solo abre una url con WebViewer. Hasta ahi funciona perfectamente.

El problema es que el sitio que abre tiene un formulario que sube informacion a una base de datos, entre ellos una imagen. Si abro la url directamente en el navegador movil funciona bien, cumple sus funciones, la magen se captura con camara o desde archivo, pero si abro la app que contiene el WebViewer ya no funciona ese input tipo FILE.

He tratado de darle los permiso necesarios, pero aun no lo logro.

El input en la pagina de php es asi:

```
<!-- Campo reporte_imagen -->
            <div class="mb-2 p-2" style="background-color: <?php echo $fondoGc; ?>">
                <label for="reporte_imagen" class="form-label fw-bold" style="color: <?php echo $cText; ?>">Soporte
                    (Imágen)</label>
                <input type="file" class="form-control rounded-0 fs-5" id="reporte_imagen" name="reporte_imagen" accept="image/*" required onchange="verificarImagen()">
                
                <script>
                    function verificarImagen() {
                        var input = document.getElementById('reporte_imagen');
                        var files = input.files;
                
                        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                            var file = files[i];
                            var imageType = /^image\//;
                
                            if (!imageType.test(file.type)) {
                                // Si el archivo no es una imagen, muestra una alerta y borra la selección
                                alert('Por favor, selecciona solo archivos de imagen.');
                                input.value = '';
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                </script>
            </div>
```

MainActivity.kt es asi:

```
package apidato.com.rhs

import android.os.Bundle
import android.webkit.GeolocationPermissions
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient
import android.webkit.WebSettings
import android.webkit.WebView
import android.webkit.WebViewClient
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var webView: WebView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Inicializar WebView
        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView)

        // Habilitar JavaScript
        webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true

        // Habilitar el acceso a la ubicación
        webView.settings.setGeolocationEnabled(true)

        // Configurar WebViewClient para evitar abrir enlaces en el navegador externo
        webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
            override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, url: String?): Boolean {
                if (!url.isNullOrBlank()) {
                    view?.loadUrl(url)
                    return true
                }
                return false
            }
        }

        // Configurar WebChromeClient para manejar la geolocalización
        webView.webChromeClient = object : WebChromeClient() {
            override fun onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(
                origin: String?,
                callback: GeolocationPermissions.Callback?
            ) {
                callback?.invoke(origin, true, false)
            }
        }

        // Cargar la URL del sitio web
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.reporte.apidato.com/movil/")
    }
}
```

Activity_mail.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"></WebView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Y AndoidManifest.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.RHS"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Por favor su apoyo